# Capitalize doesn't lowercase trailing characters

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I have this snippet:

```
{
  "Creates async dux modules": {
    "prefix": "dux-async",
    "body": [
      "// Duck module",
      "export const ${1:ModuleName}_REQUEST = \"${1}_REQUEST\";",
      "export const ${1}_SUCCESS = \"${1}_SUCCESS\";",
      "export const ${1}_ERROR = \"${1}_ERROR\";",
      "",
      "/**",
      " * State interface formodule",
      " */",
      "export interface ${1/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}State {",
```

When I tab into my snippet, I want to write `FOO`, and when I tab off, I want the last line of the snippet to be transformed to:

```
export interface FooState {
```

It appears capitalize doesn't lowercase the trailing characters, so I end up with:

```
export interface FOOState
```

Is there someway to ensure the first character is uppercase and the others are all lowercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"export interface ${1/(.)(.*)/${1:/capitalize}${2:/downcase}/}State {"
```

works. As you have seen `${1:/capitalize}` will only affect the first letter - it has no effect on the others.  So if you want to change both, you will have to split up your regex unfortunately.